# Can't create default for string array column (elixir list) in migration with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm working on a phoenix 1.3 project (using the default postgres database) and I'm trying to add a string array column with a default value of a populated list.

Here's the migration:

```
defmodule DfyDashboard.Repo.Migrations.AddLeadSourceToOffice do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:offices) do
      add :lead_sources, {:array, :string}, default: [
        "Event",
        "Facebook",
        "Google/Online",
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the migration, I get the following error:

> ** (ArgumentError) unknown default `["Event", "Facebook", "Google/Online"]` for type `{:array, :string}`. :default may be astring, number, boolean, empty list, map (when type is Map), or a fragment(...)

It seems like it isn't possible to have anything but an empty list for a default when using `{:array, input_type}`.

Is what I'm trying to do with the default actually a hack and there's a better way to do it? Or if what I'm trying to do is the preferred method, is there a hack I can use to do the same thing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why Ecto only supports empty arrays as default but you can use `fragment` for now and specify the array in PostgreSQL syntax:

```
add :lead_sources, {:array, :string},
  default: fragment("ARRAY['Event', 'Facebook', 'Google/Online']")
```

Support for empty arrays was added [in 2015](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/84c338fc628239f364c0def7e16ee51af3daf012) but not non-empty arrays. I think they would be open to adding this feature. You might want to ask the core devs on their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elixir-ecto).

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't come across fragments before, that worked great! Thanks for the tip on the mailing list, I'll do that.

Comment: very nice I was looking for a way to achieve this too